# Applying getters on a "find" query in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, getter

Sorry if this has been asked before (I've searched, honestly).

Basically, I have a simple schema:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  image: {type: String, get: getImageUrl},
  stock: {type: Number},
  price: {type: Number},
  description: String
});
```

where

```
var getImageUrl = function(imgUrl) {
  if (imgUrl.indexOf('http://') !== 0) {
    return 'http://' + os.hostname() + (app.port ? app.port : '') + '/public/' + imgUrl;
  } else {
    return imgUrl;
  }
};
```

The getter itself works, if I retrieve a specific item from the database, but not when I try to use `Product.find()` or other queries, the getter doesn't get apply, and I get the "raw" (unprocessed) property. I've tried using `Product.find({}, [], {getters: true}` to no avail. Am I missing something?

EDIT - using mongod version 1.8.5 and mongoose 2.5.10

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue today -- getters not being applied when using a find().  My workaround was to use a virtual instead and include it in the json results.

```
schema.virtual("APP_ID_URL").get(function() {
  if (this.APP_ID > 0){
    return "<a href='#'>" + this.APP_ID + "</a>";
  }
  else{
    return "";
  }
});
schema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

The schema should be under definition of getter, if you define schema after getter function definition, you can reach it. It should work according to the specification: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/getters-setters.html

Comment: In my code, the function is defined above the schema, but still no dice. I've temporarily solved my problems with a docs.map which calls doc.toObject({getters:true}), but it still bugs me.

Answer (score 0):

Update your schema to add config for populating Object and JSON

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  image: {type: String, get: getImageUrl},
  stock: {type: Number},
  price: {type: Number},
  description: String
},
{
    toObject : {getters: true},
    toJSON : {getters: true}
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2152